# Get data that is newer than given date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle

I want to see the result my data, where the date is after Jun 25th 2017. But I am seeing results from data that is older than the 25th Jun 2017. Some of it go all the way back to 1998 etc.

Here is my code:

```
   select DATE_OF_LAST_CHANGE_OF_IMMU
from recipient_treatment
where DATE_OF_LAST_CHANGE_OF_IMMU > TO_DATE('25-JUN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
;
```

Is there something in my code that isn't right for what I wish to see?

The column: `DATE_OF_LAST_CHANGE_OF_IMMU` is of type date in the table

Comment: Your code should work.  If it doesn't, then I don't believe that `DATE_OF_LAST_CHANGE_OF_IMMU` is of type date.

Comment: I'm telling you it is of type date. I checked this several times

Answer (score 0):

Please use the trunc command while filtering the date field as specified below

```
select DATE_OF_LAST_CHANGE_OF_IMMU
from recipient_treatment
where TRUNC (DATE_OF_LAST_CHANGE_OF_IMMU) > TO_DATE('25-JUN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem stated by the OP.  In addition, using a function on the column prevents the use of an index, so it is a bad idea.